# AndroidViewClient install for Windows 7

Tags: android, python, windows, automation, androidviewclient

I install Python version 2.7.9 for Windows 7, python is setup under the folder C:\Python27 and the subfolder Scripts has well the file easy_install.exe, then from the command line I run the command "easy_install --upgrade androidviewclient" as mentioned on the AndroidViewClient wiki page. The package is unstalled under the folder C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\androidviewclient-10.0.0-py2.7.egg
But I don't see any folder \examples or \src
I follow the wiki page by testing with the command "python check_import.py" but I don't find this file anywhere on my pc. I am just wondering if AndroidViewClient is setup properly, do I miss anything in the setup, or should I download something else to test ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, follow [this tutorial](http://www.darpandodiya.com/code/setup-androidviewclient-windows/). For your case you need to start on the step [8.Download zip file from GitHub].

Answer (score 0):

I think you have properly installed [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) using `easy_install`.

`/examples` and `/src` are present in the source distribution which you can clone or download from github as a [ZIP file](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/archive/master.zip). Thanks for pointing this out, I think it should be mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: thanks for your help, I download the zip file and extract to the folder C:\AndroidViewClient-master and finally pass the test as mentioned in the wiki page. I am new to Android development, so in my opinion, it is a little bit confusing, it is like there are 2 possible versions of AndroidViewClient, one from pygi and one from git, and the best way to install is via easy_install because of flexibility and future updates, download the zip and create a folder C:\AndroidViewClient-master for tests. For dependencies I think I should use the scripts culebra and dump from easy_install, right ?

Comment: Using everything from `easy_install` is what you should do. The source code is only needed if you want to contribute changes or fixes to the project.